# Cannot convert value of type 'PlayParameters?' to expected argument type '[MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters]'

Tags: swift, xcode, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am trying to create a music player with Swift and MusicKit, but I am getting this error when trying to load up the queue with the selected album from MusicKit. I don't get why the playparameters for the album and MPMusicPlayerPlayParametersQueueDescriptor are different.

```
let player = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer
let queue  = MPMusicPlayerPlayParametersQueueDescriptor(playParametersQueue: heavyRotation[album].playParameters)
player.prepareToPlay()
player.play()
```

Error on `let queue` line:

Cannot convert value of type 'PlayParameters?' to expected argument type '[MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters]'

NEW EDIT

```
        var requestURLComponents = URLComponents()
        requestURLComponents.scheme = "https"
        requestURLComponents.host = "api.music.apple.com"
        requestURLComponents.path = "/v1/me/history/heavy-rotation"
        
        requestURLComponents.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "limit", value: "5")
        ]
        
        guard let url = requestURLComponents.url else { return }
        
        let request = MusicDataRequest(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: url))
        do {
            let response = try await request.response()
            let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(MusicItemCollection<Album>.self, from: response.data)
            heavyRotation = decodedResponse
//            print(response.debugDescription)
        } catch {
            print("error")
            print(error)
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

...

```
Button(action: {
    Task {
        guard let album = heavyRotation[album] as Album? else { return }
        print(album)
        let player = ApplicationMusicPlayer.shared
        player.queue = [album]
        try await player.prepareToPlay()
        try await player.play()
    }
}) {
    Image(systemName: "play.fill")
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
        .fontSize(30)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
}
```

Comment: `PlayParameters` returns `Optional(MusicKit.PlayParameters(id: l.vvLd05C, kind: "album", dictionary: ["isLibrary": true (Bool), "kind": "album" (String), "id": "l.vvLd05C" (String)]))`

Comment: I don't actually know whether those things are different but the error is saying that you're trying to assign a single optional variable to something that wants an array of unwrapped items.  If you fix that, then the names of the underlying data types may or may not matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While MusicKit's `PlayParameters` is a structure and an opaque object, `MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters` initializers expect a `[String: Any]` dictionary. You'll have to encode and decode the `PlayParameters` to `MPMusicPlayerParameters.`

Here's your example:

```swift
guard let parameters = heavyRotation[album].playParameters else { return }

let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(parameters)
let playParameters = try JSONDecoder().decode(MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters.self, from: data)

let queue = MPMusicPlayerPlayParametersQueueDescriptor(playParametersQueue: [playParameters])

let player = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer
player.setQueue(with: queue)
player.prepareToPlay()
player.play()
```

If you're using MusicKit for Swift and its music player, you can directly set the album to the queue like this:

```swift
guard let album = heavyRotation[album] else { return }

let player = ApplicationMusicPlayer.shared
player.queue = [album]
try await player.prepareToPlay()
try await player.play()
```

---

Update - If you're trying to play an album from the library, then I had problems with that as well. As a workaround, you can get the album's **local** ID and then make another request to the catalog. If there's an album on Apple Music, then it should work.

Here's an example that works fine for me:

```swift
do {
  /// First request to get the heavy rotation albums
  guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/me/history/heavy-rotation") else { return }
  
  let request = MusicDataRequest(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: url))
  let response = try await request.response()
  
  let heavyRotationAlbums = try JSONDecoder().decode(MusicItemCollection<Album>.self, from: response.data)
  
  /// Get the first album
  guard let album = heavyRotationAlbums.first else { return }
  
  /// Get the local album ID
  let albumID = album.id

  /// Another request to get the album from Apple Music Catalog
  guard let catalogURL = URL(string: "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/me/library/albums/\(albumID)/catalog") else { return }

  let catalogRequest = MusicDataRequest(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: catalogURL))
  let catalogResponse = try await catalogRequest.response()

  let albums = try JSONDecoder().decode(MusicItemCollection<Album>.self, from: catalogResponse.data)

  /// Get the same album, but with the catalog ID
  guard let catalogAlbum = albums.first else { return }

  /// Encode the parameters 
  let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(catalogAlbum.playParameters)

  /// Decode the parameters to `MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters`
  let playParameters = try JSONDecoder().decode(MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters.self, from: data)
  
  // Create the queue
  let queue = MPMusicPlayerPlayParametersQueueDescriptor(playParametersQueue: [playParameters])
  
  let player = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer

  /// Set the queue
  player.setQueue(with: queue)
  try await player.prepareToPlay()

  /// Finally, play the album!
  player.play()
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am retrieving the heavy rotation data from here `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/get_heavy_rotation_content`. I noticed you retrieved `.playParameters.dictionary` but for me, the playParameters have no value of dictionary. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @StasysMeclazcke, I've updated the answer. Please let me know if it works now.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that solution for Apple Music but changed the following line: `guard let album = heavyRotation[album] as Album? else { return }` and it still doesn't play music... here is heavyRotation by the way `let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(MusicItemCollection<Album>.self, from: response.data)
            heavyRotation = decodedResponse`

Comment: Indeed. I've stumbled upon this problem earlier as well. It is not related to parameters, but MusicKit cannot play library songs directly, as the ID is different from what is there on Apple Music.

I did file feedback for this as well. 

For a workaround, if your heavy rotation album is something you added from Apple Music, I've updated the code. It works perfectly for me. Let me know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I updated code in my response for my full implementation of what you posted &

Comment: Added comments with the update. This one should work, hopefully.

Comment: @RudrankRiyam Brother, you have saved my nerves and made me so happy!!! Than you very much!!!:)